# How to change page title for custom retailer signup form page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, page-title

I have created a CMS page in magento says `Retailer Signup`  and set below xml in `Layout Update XML`

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="retailer/customer/form/register.phtml">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Where `retailer/customer/form/register.phtml` is my custom form for retailer sign up. All are working but the title of page says `Create New Customer Account`.

I want to change it by `Create New Retailer Account`.

How to change page title only for custom signup form page?

Answer (score 0):

< reference name="head">
< action method="setForcedTitle">< title>Create New Retailer Account.< /title>< /action>
< /reference>

you use this code to set title

Comment: I have already tried this and also `setTitle`  but it is not working for me.

Comment: $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Create New 
Retailer Account'));

    before 

$this->renderLayout();  in your controller action